# How do I filter on values in a table, but only when it has records?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, filter

I have a table `Tran` with transaction records.

I have two tables, `Parameters1` and `Parameters2`, which are used to filter results when selecting from the `Tran` table a la:

```
SELECT *  
FROM  
     Tran t JOIN  
     Parameters1 p1 ON T.code1 = p1.code1  
     Parameters2 p2 ON T.code2 = p2.code2  
WHERE p1.code1 is not null AND
      p2.code2 is not null
```

Sometimes `Parameters1` or `Parameters2` is empty.

What I want is for the filtering to happen only if the `Parameters` tables have records. In other words, if `Parameters1` is empty, don't use it to filter, and vice versa.  Same goes for `Parameters2`.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you mean, `SELECT t.* FROM Tran t JOIN...` In other words, when the parameter tables are empt,y do you still want to project their attributes in the resulset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd normally do this using [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html), since coding up dynamic search conditions with static SQL is generally hackish. If you are interested in this approach I highly recommend Erland Sommarskog's page on [dynamic SQL for SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#dynsql). He has a great case study with plenty of example code on how to do exactly what you're asking for.

## 1. Setup

Whether you use dynamic or static SQL, you should first determine upfront what filters apply:

```
DECLARE @p1_filter BIT;
DECLARE @p2_filter BIT;

SET @p1_filter = 0;
SET @p2_filter = 0;

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) * FROM Parameters1)
BEGIN
   SET @p1_filter = 1;
END;

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) * FROM Parameters2)
BEGIN
   SET @p2_filter = 1;
END;
```

## 2.a. Dynamic SQL

If you're going the dynamic SQL route you'd then do:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Tran T ';

IF (@p1_filter = 1)
BEGIN
   SET @sql = @sql + 'INNER JOIN Parameters1 p1 ON T.code1 = p1.code1 ';
END;

IF (@p2_filter = 1)
BEGIN
   SET @sql = @sql + 'INNER JOIN Parameters2 p2 ON T.code2 = p2.code2 ';
END;

EXECUTE sp_executesql
   @statement = @sql
;
```

## 2.b.i. Static SQL: Sub-SELECTs in the WHERE clause

Otherwise, you'd continue with this ugly (and probably poorly performing) static SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tran T
WHERE 
   (
         T.code1 IN (SELECT code1 FROM Parameters1)
      OR (@p1_filter = 0)
   )
   AND
   (
         T.code2 IN (SELECT code2 FROM Parameters2)
      OR (@p2_filter = 0)
   )
;
```

Erland also presents static SQL approaches like this one on [that same page](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#static) I referred to earlier. You may find a better approach there.

## 2.b.ii. Static SQL: LEFT OUTER JOIN

You can also go with this approach, which you proposed in the comments on this answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
                   Tran T
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Parameters1 p1
      ON T.code1 = p1.code1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Parameters2 p2
      ON T.code2 = p2.code2
WHERE
       T.code1 = 
          CASE
             WHEN @p1_filter = 1
                THEN p1.code1
             ELSE T.code1
          END
   AND T.code2 =
          CASE
             WHEN @p2_filter = 1
                THEN p2.code2
             ELSE T.code2
          END
;
```

Comment: The first suggestion you have (determining the filters first) is the approach I will have to go with I think. I was hoping for something a little more elegant but it is what it is.

Comment: One change though...I will `left outer join` the parameter tables, and then use the bit to determine, with a CASE statement, whether to filter on that table or not, like `WHERE t.Code1 = CASE WHEN @p1_filter = 1 THEN p1.Code1 ELSE t.Code1 END`.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde - Note that the first block of code in my answer is just the setup.  You then follow it immediately with either the second or third block, depending on what approach you want to take.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde - I think that would work as well; it may even outperform the static SQL solution I proposed.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I appreciate you helping me think this through. :-)

Comment: "dynamic search conditions with static SQL is generally hackish" -- funny, I think that this is the norm and that it is dynamic SQL that is hackish ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen - Ideally, SQL would make it easy to solve this kind of problem in a way that is practical and efficient. Since it does not, dynamic SQL was born--originally a hack. Since then, dynamic SQL has become a well-understood and very well-suited solution for this type of problem, and in comparison it is the original static SQL approaches that now look like hacks to me. :)

Comment: @RichardDesLonde - You're welcome. It was a good SQL problem.

Comment: @NickChammas: I think you criticism should be attributed to the SQL Server product, or perhaps users for being satisfied with a hack rather than demanding an efficient product. SQL generally has many faults but I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: @onedaywhen - I don't see what this has to do with SQL Server. Can you name an RDBMS that can be queried with SQL that solves this type of problem in a way that is easily maintainable and fast? I get the impression that SQL was not designed to handle dynamically defined join or filter conditions, hence the need for dynamic SQL. Do you disagree?

Comment: @NickChammas: are you referring specifically to parameter values passed in from calling applications? There is a SQL Standard called SQL/PSM ("Persistent Stored Modules") but T-SQL makes no claims to be compliant with it. The 'regular' SQL Standards (e.g. SQL-92) does not deal with input parameters at all. So yes, I think the criticism about poor performance associated with input parameters should be levelled at the SQL Server product.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM Tran T  
RIGHT JOIN Parameters1 p1 ON T.code1 = p1.code1  
JOIN Parameters2 p2 ON T.code2 = p2.code2  
WHERE p1.code1 is not null AND p2.code2 is not null
```

Comment: That's the same problem, only in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

How about the `exists`

```
select * from Tran t

where exists(select 1 from Parameters1 p1 where t.code1 = p.code1)

and  exists(select 1 from Parameters2 p2 where t.code2 = p.code2)
```

Comment: It needs to be OR in cases where one or the other of the tables is empty...that's the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you only want results if BOTH have results? Also, I'm guessing that the p referred to in your joins is supposed to be the table alias for parameter1 (p1) and parameter2 (p2) and not just (p) as in your question.

If so, then just select t.* and LEFT JOIN both of the Parameters tables such as;

```
SELECT t.*  
FROM  
     Tran t 
     LEFT JOIN Parameters1 p1 ON T.code1 = p1.code1  
     LEFT JOIN Parameters2 p2 ON T.code2 = p2.code2  
WHERE p1.code1 is not null AND
      p2.code2 is not null
```

Comment: Problem here is, if either table returns no records, this query will return no records either.

Comment: Are you sure? Try with the SELECT changed to SELECT t.code1, t.code2, p1.code1 or p2.code2. The SELECT above should translate to SELECT ALL trans t and any matching parameters will be included, otherwise they'll have null values. INNER JOINS will only return if there is a match, LEFT JOINS should return a valid value if there is a match or NULL if there isn't (which is what you are trying to achieve I think). Try it out.

Comment: I believe the Richard wants to filter out records from `Tran` by means of the `INNER JOIN` when either of the `Parameters` tables have records. Using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` negates that purpose, since all the rows from `Tran` will always be returned.

Comment: Yeah, but then the filtering occurs in the where clause via the IS NOT NULL clauses. It will only return trans records that have a corresponding Parameter1 and Parameter2. I'm actually confused by the table structure a bit. If t does have code1 and code 2 and parameter1 and 2 tables actually have code1 and code2 respectively, then you could feasibly have a FK constraint on these enforcing referential integrity and simply check for t.code1 IS NOT NULL and t.code2 IS NOT NULL. I am beginning to think I am missing something in this question though :)

Comment: From the original question: "What I want is for the filtering to happen only if the Parameters tables have records." In your case, if both `Parameters` tables are empty then no records from `Tran` will be returned, instead of all records as the OP wants.

Comment: Hmm, OK, then mess about with the WHERE clause to arrive at what you are after. For example, WHERE (p1.code1 IS NOT NULL AND p2.code2 IS NOT NULL) OR (p1.code1 IS NULL AND p2.code2 IS NULL) -- If you only want results where there are no apparent parameters. Make similar mods if you are only interested in one parameter or another.

Comment: I'm afraid even that is not enough. The OP wants to be able to filter on either `Parameters` table, on both, or on neither, depending on which of them have or don't have rows. I don't see how you can accomplish that with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and these `WHERE` conditions.